# Why is my array empty after I populated it in this each loop?

Tags: ruby

Learning Ruby and trying out problems on Coderbyte. This code is supposed to find the number of numbers between numbers in an array. So `[4,8,6]` should return 2 (it needs 5 and 7 to be consecutive). `[5,10,15]` should return 8 and `[-2,10,4]` should return 10.

My solution is to get the difference between a number and its next greatest number, minus one, which is how many numbers are between them.

When I `p new_arr` inside my each loop, it has the correct array: `[1,1]` in the first case, `[4,4]` in the next case and `[5,5]` in the last case. But when I exit the each loop, the array is empty again and `new_arr.reduce(:+)` returns nil.

I can't understand why because I defined `new_arr` outside the `each` loop. Is there some scope issue I'm missing here?

```
def Consecutive(arr)

  arr.sort!
  num_of_nums = 0
  new_arr = []
  i = 0
  arr.each do
    return if i == arr.length - 1
    num_of_nums = (arr[i+1] - arr[i]) - 1
    new_arr << num_of_nums
    i+=1
    p new_arr
  end
  new_arr.reduce(:+)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything if `i == arr.length - 1`.

You probably want to return this value:

```
return new_arr.reduce(:+) if i == arr.length - 1
```

or use `break` instead of `return`, so you just break out of the innermost loop.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped me solve a bug in another problem as well where I didn't properly understand the difference between return and break.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work mainly because of the line `return if i == arr.length - 1`. You want to break out of the loop, but you are actually `return`ing out of the method, which is not what you want.

I think you are a bit confused about how to use the `each` method, because you are also using an iterator (`i`) unnecessarily. Your code would be better with the `each_with_index` method. I think there is a better approach, though.

What we really want to do is find all the numbers in `(arr[0]..arr[-1]).to_a` that aren't in `arr`, right?

```
arr.sort!
((arr[0]..arr[-1]).to_a - arr).count
```

That will give you the number of numbers between the lowest number in the array (`arr[0]` after it is sorted) and the highest number in the array (`arr[-1]` after it is sorted) that aren't in the original array.